# Override at_exit method

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm trying to write an unattended install script in bash for my dotfiles that asks for `sudo` once at the beginning and keeps it alive throughout the whole process. I'm finding some roadblocks when installing Homebrew, though.

It turns out the [install script](https://github.com/Homebrew/install/blob/master/install#L108) comes with this:

```
at_exit { Kernel.system "/usr/bin/sudo", "-k" }
```

This leaves me with no option I know about since `sudo -k` kills the sudo timeout unconditionally. I have pretty close to zero knowledge in Ruby but I have the feeling my best bet is trying to override `at_exit` from outside the install script at invoke time. I don't know if it's possible and my Google skills are failing me on this.

I invoke the install script like this:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null
```

If possible I would like to avoid forking the script and having to keep it up to date, so any hint or workaround will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to do it in the Ruby side, you can override the `at_exit` method by just defining it again.

```
def at_exit(*);end;
```

So you can invoke the install script this way:

```
ruby -e "def at_exit(*);end;$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to remove that line from the script before executing it:

```
sed 's/at_exit.*sudo.*-k.*$//'
```

As a full command-line:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install | sed 's/at_exit.*sudo.*-k.*$//')" < /dev/null
```